# How to define where colspan with phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I wish to define it's a row with usual cells or colspan. Range of cells -- const.

When cells are contained by different data -- no problem, I use strlen.

```
But,

if 
-----------
A1 = '';
B1 = '';
C1 = '';
-----------
or
-----------
A1:С1 = '';
-----------

how to define?
```

---

Sheet excel :

```
            A1      B1     C1
        -------------------------
row_1 : |       |       |       |      
        -------------------------
        -------------------------
row_2 : |                       |       
        -------------------------
```

How to define where colspan with phpexcel ?

Comment: If you simply want to `merge` cells, look at section `4.6.34` of the developer documentation (entitled `Merge/unmerge cells`). The code would be `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:C1');`

Comment: Thanks, Mark. No, I wish to understand, when I read with phpExcel they are merged or not.

Comment: When I read my file.xlsx with PHPExcel ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getMergeCells();
```

will return an array of all merged cell blocks within a spreadsheet, looking something like:

```
array(3) {
  ["A3:A5"]=>
  string(5) "A3:A5"
  ["C1:E1"]=>
  string(5) "C1:E1"
  ["C3:E5"]=>
  string(5) "C3:E5"
}
```

If you want to check whether a particular cell falls within a merge block, you can use something like:

```
$myCell = 'D3';
$isInMerge = false;
$cell = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($myCell);
foreach($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getMergeCells() as $mergeRange) {
    if ($cell->isInRange($mergeRange)) {
        echo 'Cell ', $cell->getCoordinate(), ' is in merge range ', $mergeRange, PHP_EOL;
        $isInMerge = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$isInMerge) {
    echo 'Cell ', $cell->getCoordinate(), ' is not part of a merge range', PHP_EOL;
}
```